# Use a generic parameter as a Literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typing

I'm trying to play around with creating an api and I have different functions that handle requests to the api.

Some of the methods return a `204` rersponse and I want to typehint the return type of the method to a response with the statuscode 201.

```py
def something() -> Response[204]:
    ...
```

I thought of creating a subclass of the real `Response` class that will be returned, and then just set the `status_code` variable to the Literal `T`.

```py
class Response(Generic[T], TheOtherResponseClass):
    status_code: Literal[T]
```

My question is now how do I get the generic parameter `T` work with the `Literal` object from the `typing` module, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I can think of:

```py
from typing import Generic, Literal, TypeVar

class TheOtherResponseClass:
    status_code: int

T = TypeVar('T', bound=int)

class Response(Generic[T], TheOtherResponseClass):
    status_code: T

class Response204(Response[Literal[204]]):
    status_code: Literal[204] = 204

reveal_type(Response204.status_code)
```

Running `mypy` on that file will give you

```
note: Revealed type is "Literal[204]"
```